# Preserve color of transparent pixels using CGContextDrawimage?

Tags: ios, graphics, core-graphics

I'm loading image data from a TIFF stored on disk in to a buffer which I subsequently use to create an OpenGL texture. I'm getting at the data by writing to a `CGContext`. The original image is 100% white on every single pixel. The only thing that changes from one pixel to the next is the alpha value.

When I write to the `CGContext`, the color of the transparent pixels isn't preserved. "Why do you care about the color of transparent pixels" you ask? When the image is scaled, the color of the transparent pixels can become visible, creating ugly dark outline artifacts.

I've tried reading the data directly from the `CGImage` into a buffer and using that buffer to create my texture (using `CGImageGetDataProvider(image)`), but this only works in cases where the color space of the CGImage is RGBA. Presumably, `CGContextDrawimage` handles converting from one color space to another.

Is there any way I can tell `CGContextDrawimage` to preserve the color of transparent pixels? Or am I going to have to load my images some other way?

Comment: while creating the `CGContext` using `CGBitmapContextCreate` use the bitmap info flag as `kCGImageAlphaPreMultipliedLast`.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "preserve the color of transparent pixels." Can you show us a picture of what's happening vs. what you expect to happen?

Comment: @user1118321 I'm looking at the actual memory of the image buffer. In the original image, every single pixel has an RBG value of 255, regardless of what the alpha value is. After I draw this origin image into the context, pixels in the context buffer have RGB values of 0 unless the A value is non-zero.

Comment: @kaar3k I'm already using `kCGImageAlphaPreMultipliedLast` to create my buffer. Fully transparent pixels don't appear to copy over.

Comment: Can you please add your code so that can see where it is going wrong.

Comment: I can share code, but I'd want to clean it up before I post it. Before I do that, can you confirm that you've seen color values preserved on calls to CGContextDrawimage even when pixels are 100% transparent (alpha = 0)? It makes sense to me that a drawing function would ignore these transparent pixels, and not bother copying them.

Comment: @morgancodes No, that's not how premultiplied alpha works. If you have any pixels where the alpha is 0 and RGB are *not* 0, then either your image is not premultiplied, or it is constructed incorrectly. If you have straight (non-premultiplied) alpha, then use `kCGImageAlphaLast` (or `First` as appropriate) for the bitmap info flag.

Comment: I hate answers like the ones in the comments.  @user1118321, the problem is that writing to the CGContext DOES premultiply the alpha. I'm dealing with this now and stumbled here while searching for a solution.  A source of 1,1,1,0 after being drawn to a CGContext becomes 0,0,0,0 and there are reasons why in my particular case I can't have that.  So for me it looks like the CGContext IS the problem. By the way.. not every "image" is just an image.